# Two ViewModels for a single View at MvvmCross

Tags: mono, viewmodel, xamarin, mvvmcross

Is it possible to use two ViewModels for a single View at MvvmCross?

The reason is an existing Core library which already has navigation in place and a working app on top of it. Now I need to create another app and leverage the only View for two ViewModels (in core lib there is one view navigated to another using ShowViewModel and I just want to stay at the same view and change my datacontext).

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes

- you can continue to use `ShowViewModel` and change the way navigation happens by overriding the presenter - see Custom Presenters in [the wiki](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup#Custom-Presenters)
- or you can use a different navigation mechanism entirely - there's nothing forcing you to use `ShowViewModel`

Comment: I forced to use ShowViewModel by existing app and core library which is not the case to rewrite. Thing with custom presenter could work for me. Thanks!